# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view Error

Tags: android, viewgroup

I have a strange Error with a ViewGroup.
For my main View I use classes in this links [ViewFlow project](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
        at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:4153)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:4090)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.scrollToRectOrFocus(ViewRootImpl.java:2129)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1849)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1641)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2449)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error happens when I try to go back to this view with an Intent or a finish(); method in an other View. When I use the Back Button it's not a problem.

So i don't know why I have this Error.
Thanks for your Help.

Comment: which party of the code need you ? My initialization of the viewFlow, the code of the Viewflow (already linked) or the code of my second activity where i do the finish(); ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have the same problem. I use a ViewFlow as the parent view and several GridView as child views.This error happens when I press the Home key and restart the activity again after I scrolled these child views left and right.

Here is my solution:

```
mViewFlow.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Of course, you can config it in layout.xml.

Hope that can help you.

Comment: please describe solution.

Comment: Hi Parixit, I'm sorry to response to you so late. I have write a blog to analyse this exception, here is the link: http://www.cnblogs.com/monodin/p/3675040.html

Comment: It is written by Chinese, so you may don't understand. But the solutions are at the end of that blog which includes lots of code, and I think you can get some things from them. Also, you are warmly invited to make contact with me. Here is my e-mail: dyj_henu@126.com

Comment: thank you. BUt personal contact is not preferable. Its better that all here get the answer other than personal contact.

Comment: TO Parixt：I can't agree with you any more. But I have few idle time to translate them every day. And I will take two weeks off from this weekend. After that,I will translate them as soon as possible.

Comment: Is this necessary if I'm using a ```androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView```?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when deleting item from recycler view which contains EditText. Just before notifying adapter that item was deleted I used

```
(requireContext() as Activity).currentFocus?.clearFocus()
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using AdMob banners, add this line,
`adView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);`
Some banner ads or the AdView itself may request focus and that may trigger this `parameter must be a descendant of this view` error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem with adding scroll listener.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View currentFocus = ((Activity)mContext).getCurrentFocus();
    if (currentFocus != null) {
        currentFocus.clearFocus();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_stat_header,
                    parent, false);
```

Here, `parent` is the ViewGroup parameter in the getView.