# Another java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view

Tags: android, listview, exception, expandablelistview

Users are getting the following exception in my app on certain phones. I tried reproducing the error myself but couldn't . I searched through stack overflow for similar problems and tried their solutions but none seem to be working.

Here are the answers I already tried:

1. [Preventing/catching "IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100555/preventing-catching-illegalargumentexception-parameter-must-be-a-descendant-of/12892317#12892317)
2. [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721907/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-must-be-a-descendant-of-this-view?rq=1)
3. Setting the following attribute: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

I have an edittext but it's outside of the expandablelistview.

I am trying to find an explanation on why this is happening and what might cause it to happen. I apologize but I can't post any code.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of
>   this view
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:4568)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:4505)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder.init(ViewGroup.java:6743)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup$ViewLocationHolder.obtain(ViewGroup.java:6680)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup$ChildListForAccessibility.init(ViewGroup.java:6638)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup$ChildListForAccessibility.obtain(ViewGroup.java:6606)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.addChildrenForAccessibility(ViewGroup.java:1697)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(ViewGroup.java:2525)
>          at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5213)
>          at android.widget.AdapterView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AdapterView.java:946)
>          at android.widget.AbsListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AbsListView.java:1449)
>          at android.widget.ListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(ListView.java:3781)
>          at android.widget.ExpandableListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(ExpandableListView.java:1348)
>          at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:5174)
>          at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5161)
>          at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:811)
>          at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:834)
>          at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:834)
>          at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:720)
>          at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:147)
>          at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$300(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:49)
>          at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:971)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code where it's crashing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was caused by adding a wrongly inflated header to two different listviews.

I inflated a view using `listViewA` as the parent and adding it to `listViewB` also. As such:

```
RelativeLayout listViewHeader = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewheader, listViewA, false);

// Set some views

listViewA.addHeaderView(listViewHeader);
listViewB.addHeaderView(listViewHeader);
```

I fixed it by changing the above to the following:

```
RelativeLayout listViewHeaderA = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewheader, listViewA, false);
RelativeLayout listViewHeaderB = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewheader, listViewB, false);

listViewA.addHeaderView(listViewHeaderA);
listViewB.addHeaderView(listViewHeaderB);
```

As for reproducing the crash, the problem happened when Google Talk Back is turned on. Here is my take on the situation: Google Talk Back does text to speech on views that are in focus (either by touch or auto-focused). When it enters a screen with multiple views requesting focus, it reads the views according to a hierarchy/order.

If you have a layout (parent) with three views (children), Google Talk Back checks how the views are arranged and then reads them accordingly. For example, in a layout with three textview lined up horizontally, Google Talk Back may read the left textview first, then the middle one, then the one on the right.

In my case, I was inflating a header view with `listViewA` as the parent and adding that view to both `listViewA` and `listViewB`. When `listViewB`gains focus and Google Talk Back tries to interpret its children, it sees the header view is not a child of the list and throws the exception. This also happens if I inflate the header view with no parents (null).

Comment: really helped me.. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Thank you very much - this helped me a lot!

Comment: Does this happen when we inflate the same layout.xml for different listViews in a viewPager?

Answer (score 1):

I have append on scroll listener in ScrollView
and **solve problem**

```
 lst_payment_info.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL == scrollState) {
                View currentFocus = getCurrentFocus();
                if (currentFocus != null) {
                    currentFocus.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error when Google TalkBack is turned on. In my case, I was inflating a view with the boolean attachToParent true.So by making it false worked for me.