# notifyItemRangeChanged() causing crash RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview, gridlayoutmanager

layout design:

```
HorizontalScrollView-parent, holding RV[
    RecyclerView=>(GridLayoutManager) (orientation verticle)]
```

Which will basically do a two way scroll. This UI is built for TV. The focused row in this grid will show extra detail and other rows wont. So whenever there is a focus change from one row to another in `onFocusChange` i modify the `dataset` of the `Adapter` and call `notifyItemRangeChanged()`.

This works fine when the rows length exceeds that of the vertical length of the screen, i.e. vertically scrollable. The crash happens say like if there is less number of rows (like 4).

Error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:5937)
at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:5866)
at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.isWithinDeltaOfScreen(HorizontalScrollView.java:1168)
at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onSizeChanged(HorizontalScrollView.java:1569)
at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:19719)
at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:19680)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19583)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1780)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1546)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
```

I tried calling notifydatasetchange, but that will return getAdapterPosition = -1 which will not result in focus change from 1 row to another

Since the Adapter code length exceeds character length set by stackoverflow i am providing drive link for the same.
[Adapter and viewholder layout code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oXDc_rb3DeD3O26UcgGBh5Sl4Ac9-EuA?usp=sharing)

No crash when scrolled vertically 
[image: Items without crash]

Crash on vertical scroll
[image: Items with crash]

Comment: can you post your code, adapter you are written

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585561/another-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-must-be-a-descendant-of-th) maybe help you

Comment: thanks, have checked them, sadly not relevant to me.

Comment: Can't really help with only the stacktrace attached to the question.

Comment: @hardartcore I will add adapter code and viewholder layout code, will that do ?

Comment: Try this: `your_scrollview_object.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);`

Comment: @Ümañg ßürmån thanks, still same error

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot for the issue. and I am more concerned for your comment "The crash happens say like if there is less number of rows (like 4)."-- Wanted to view the UI.

Comment: @jiteshmohite please check added screenshots

Comment: @DJphy:  Is recyclerView only contains four item inside second screenshot?

Comment: @jiteshmohite yes, any number of rows less than the vertical length of the screen, when tried to scroll using focus it crashes, works fine if more number of items(rows) are present

Comment: @DJphy I'm not sure if this will help, but you should bind the views in `onBindViewHolder` without delay because that's when the `RecyclerView` performs updates on its views afterwards. I suspect if you bind your views with `Handler.postDelayed`, then your binding may fail or encounter unexpected behavior. So try to remove the delay block, and you probably have to find another way to load your data asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when the items in the recyclerview are focusable. 
Try the following things:

**Option 1**
user `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in scrollview

**Option 2**
Append your custom ScrollListener to your Activity, the purpose is when RV start scrolling, clear current focus.

```
protected class FocusableScrollListner implements OnScrollListener {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // do nothing 
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL == scrollState) {
                View currentFocus = getCurrentFocus();
                if (currentFocus != null) {
                    currentFocus.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**Option 3:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View currentFocus = ((Activity)context).getCurrentFocus();
    if (currentFocus != null) {
        currentFocus.clearFocus();
    }
}
```

there may be some other alternatives depending upon your code, you have to clear the focus.

Comment: sure i will check this out, appreciate your help

Comment: Please let us know if it helped, else please share the concern, would try to figure out.

Comment: tried your solution, didnt work, i cannot use option 2 since my platform is tv, here touch doesn't work, it works with remote control navigation. also i cannot clear focus in obindviewholder since i am registered to onfocuschange