# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, viewgroup

I'm getting multiple crashes with this message `parameter must be a descendant of this view` from various Redmi devices. I have read similar questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't understand their solutions. As these logs don't include the activity or function names, I'm confused about where to start.

My app has lot of activities and fragments. How can I find the component causing this crash?

Device 1 log,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:6362)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:6291)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.scrollToRectOrFocus(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3250)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2076)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8506)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1076)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:897)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:826)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1061)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8059)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Device 2 log,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:6417)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:6343)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.isWithinDeltaOfScreen(ScrollView.java:1286)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onSizeChanged(ScrollView.java:1701)
       at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:23557)
       at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:23507)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23356)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecoratedWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9878)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1689)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:804)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23361)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6534)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3702)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3160)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2129)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8603)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:975)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:799)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:734)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:960)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7864)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

Device 3 log,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:6208)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:6137)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.isWithinDeltaOfScreen(ScrollView.java:1288)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onSizeChanged(ScrollView.java:1703)
       at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:22276)
       at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:22226)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22085)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecoratedWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9878)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1689)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:812)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22088)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6325)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3191)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2701)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1819)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7781)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1031)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:854)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:789)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1016)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Device 4 log,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:6415)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:6341)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.isWithinDeltaOfScreen(ScrollView.java:1286)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onSizeChanged(ScrollView.java:1701)
       at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:23462)
       at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:23412)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23261)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecoratedWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9878)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1689)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:804)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23266)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6532)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3708)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3166)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2135)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8624)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:975)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:799)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:734)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:960)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

Device 5 log,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:6365)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:6290)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.isWithinDeltaOfScreen(ScrollView.java:1315)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onSizeChanged(ScrollView.java:1730)
       at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:23499)
       at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:23451)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23300)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecoratedWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9878)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1689)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:829)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23305)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6482)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3298)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2235)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9028)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1105)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:896)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:815)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1090)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:223)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

I'm not able to reproduce this crash. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show your recyclerView layout.

Comment: can i view your layout xml file

Answer (score 2):

The error is being thrown by the following code in *ViewGroup.java*. See [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java;drc=b23c8c8e87972380cdf77e6bacbf9ae608ebcf40;l=6242).

```
/**
 * Helper method that offsets a rect either from parent to descendant or
 * descendant to parent.
 */
void offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(View descendant, Rect rect,
        boolean offsetFromChildToParent, boolean clipToBounds) {

...

    // now that we are up to this view, need to offset one more time
    // to get into our coordinate space
    if (theParent == this) {
        if (offsetFromChildToParent) {
            rect.offset(descendant.mLeft - descendant.mScrollX,
                    descendant.mTop - descendant.mScrollY);
        } else {
            rect.offset(descendant.mScrollX - descendant.mLeft,
                    descendant.mScrollY - descendant.mTop);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("parameter must be a descendant of this view");
    }
}
...
```

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30631099/6287910) related to the same error message, it looks like there was an attempt to add a view to two *ViewGroups*.  The "parameter" in the message is the "descendant" *View* and "this view" is the *ViewGroup*.

I will guess that you are doing something similar, although there is not enough information to immediately identify the source of the problem. A view can only have one parent.

Comment: Does this happen when we inflate the same layout.xml for different listViews in a viewPager?

Comment: If you inflate the view twice then no. If you inflate the view once and use it twice then yes; you could see that problem.

Comment: I have a ViewPager with 3 fragments. Each fragment contains a ListView that inflates the same layout xml for list item.

Comment: From the stack traces you posted, it looks like the problem is happening during layout of some set of views. From what is printed it looks like the layout has a _LinearLayout_, a _RecyclerView_ and a _ViewPager_ since classes related to these types of views are mentioned. Hopefully, you just have one layout that fits this description. It may be helpful if you could identify the related code and post it and the associated layout(s).

Comment: Stack traces 2-5 are the same error. At least the calling stack is the same with just different line number probably due to different APIs. The first error may be related, but it may not be the same error as the others since its stack trace is so different.

Answer (score 2):

**replaced All Your**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
</ScrollView>
```

**To**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

***I Replace in my project and all issues are resolve now***

Comment: I have changed it. But still getting this error.

Comment: i am also facing this issue though i have replace with NestedScrollView, Any help?